# Add first element of array to the same array

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation, element

I have an array of objects. I need to add the first element of that array to the end of it, so the first and last elements are the same. I've came up with this but I feel like there is a better solution out there.

`points.Concat(new[] { points[0] }).ToArray()`

Full context:

```
public static Vertex[] CreateLineStrip(Color color, params Vector2f[] points)
{
    return CreateVertices(color, points.Concat(new[] { points[0] }).ToArray());
}
```

`CreateVertices` projects the given array of points to an array of vertices.

Comment: If you want a varying number of elements I wouldn't use an array to start with. Any reason you can't use a `List<T>`? Then just: `list.Add(list[0])`

Comment: @JonSkeet `points` is used as a `params` parameter to a method. Can I use lists with `params`?

Comment: Do you mean it comes *from* a `params` parameter? It would be nice to know more context. (Even if you *start* with it as an array, or *end* with it as an array, that doesn't mean you need it as an array at every stage...)

Comment: I've added the full context to my question.

Comment: Well does `CreateVertices` have to take an array as a parameter? What does it do? Could it take an `IEnumerable<Vector2f>`?

Comment: `CreateVertices` also takes a `params Vector2f[] points`, `CreateLineStrip` is a kind-of wrapper for it.

Comment: The question is whether you *need* to use arrays all over the place like this. Of course, your existing code is pretty simple. How important is performance to you?

Comment: I'd prefer to keep things simple and not have many arrays-to-lists (and vice-versa) conversions. If that's creates problems in performance, I'll gladly change it to something better.

Comment: Well currently you're copying everything all the time. That may or may not be an issue. We don't know how large your arrays are, or how important performance is, or how often you're calling these methods. That makes it very hard to give advice.

Comment: The arrays those methods receive are very small, mostly less than ten elements in them. Performance is needed since this is part of a game but these methods aren't called often so their performance shouldn't be a large issue.

Comment: In that case, you're probably fine to stick with what you've got for now.

Comment: Inline with your comments i've updated my answer, you may or may not like this sort of things

Answer (score 0):

Given the following extension method, inline with your comments, you could add some syntactical sugar

However there is nothing really gained here, apart from a shiny new extension method

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
   static public T[] Append<T>(this T[] array, T item)
   {
      return array.Concat(new[] { item }).ToArray();
   }
}

public static Vertex[] CreateLineStrip(Color color, params Vector2f[] points)
{
    return CreateVertices(color, points.Append(points[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void MyMethod(params Contact[] contacts)
        {
            var list = new List<Contact>(contacts);
            list.Add(list[0]);

            // ... do your thing
        }
```